# Can not see some local variables in debugger within intellij for some scala programs

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

As described in the title there are some cases that Intellij is not able to recognized/display some of the local variables.

[image]

As can be seen, some of the local variables e.g. outarr and arrptr are already set: but the debugger does not know about them.

I am running inside IJ 13.1.4 in a maven project and have enabled debugging info as follows:

```
      <configuration>
        <args>
                ..
          <arg>-feature</arg>
            <arg>-g:notc</arg>
          </args>
         ..
```

My question is about : does anyone recognize this problem and has come up with workaround(s) for it?

**Update**  Per suggestion on an answer here is the result of trying Alt-F8

[image]

Comment: If you click on `mergeTest():92` in the `Frames` Tab in Debugger you should be able to see `aptr` and `outarr`. By looking at the name of your current stack frame, it seems that it's an anonymous inner class (Scala compiler creates them for different control structures and also anonymous functions). So by moving between frames you can find variables in context.

Comment: In Latest version of Scala plugin there is an `$outer` variable in variables tab which makes debugging easier. I'm not sure whether it is available in all versions or not.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari  I noticed that my version on this machine is actually quite old 13.1.1  Going to upgrade to latest 13.1.5.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari After updating to 13.1.5 (ultimate) still same behavior: only certain variables show up.

Comment: What about navigating between frames? Still no success with that? That way at least you can see all variables in current stack frame which is quite enough for many use cases.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari  You can see in the OP that the variables required are on the topmost frame. Navigating to different frames does not help in terms of viewing the variables in that frame.

Comment: This happens to me everyday and I die a little each time.

Answer (score 3):

This is mainly because debugging anonymous functions is inherently a hard job!

What you can do is to try to open `$outer` in `variables` section in debugger which means the anonymous function containing current context.

By doing this repeatedly (find `$outer` of that `$outer` again) there is a good chance you can find your variables.

[image]

If `$outer` is not available just navigate to the previous stack frame by clicking on it on `Frames` tab in Debugger.

Comment: So you can confirm that there is no `$outer` in your `Variables` section?

Comment: Just FYI, you can navigate between frames also with a hot key which makes debugging easier: <key>Ctrl + Alt + Up/Down</key>. You can also drop a frame by right-clicking on it and start from scratch.

Comment: Keep those hotkey tips coming!  What do you mean by the tag/end-tag <key></key> ?

Comment: confirmed: there is NO $outer. The screenshot in OP shows all the variables available (no scrolling down to see more..)

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Up/Down (Cmd + Alt + Up/Down in Mac)

Comment: I am going to upvote your answer for the Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down - that's useful

Answer (score 1):

You can try Alt+F8 to jump into expression evaluator, usually from that window I can reach all variables that are reachable from breakpoint.

Comment: nice idea, I will try that. It appears the whole build env got corrupted in this case.

Comment: Tried it, gave same "Cannot find local variable" error (see update to OP)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in IJ 2017: I declared and initialized two local booleans, but only the second one was displayed in the debugger.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> allowed me to evaluate the expression used to initialize that boolean but did not find the value of the boolean itself either.

Changing the expression slightly by comparing the result to `true` before assigning it made it work. So in your case, maybe varying the initialisation might work too.

Comment: Three years ago and I do not have a project with that issue presently - but your tip seems useful so I will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

It seem's jdk's bug, use jdk8 instead ,problems will resolves.For more info see: [Debugger cannot see local variable in a Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895708/debugger-cannot-see-local-variable-in-a-lambda)

Comment: Line 71 is not inside a closure.

Answer (score 0):

1. when i add the following code, issue appear
2. use jdk8, idea2019.1.3
3. in my case，just click `this` in variables, and you can see the value

```
def singlePassMultiFilter[T](
      rdd: RDD[T],
      f1: T => Boolean,
      f2: T => Boolean,
      level: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY
  ): (RDD[T], RDD[T], Boolean => Unit) = {
  val tempRDD = rdd mapPartitions { iter =>
    val abuf1 = ArrayBuffer.empty[T]
    val abuf2 = ArrayBuffer.empty[T]
    for (x <- iter) {
      if (f1(x)) abuf1 += x
      if (f2(x)) abuf2 += x
    }
    Iterator.single((abuf1, abuf2))
  }
  tempRDD.persist(level)
  val rdd1 = tempRDD.flatMap(_._1)
  val rdd2 = tempRDD.flatMap(_._2)
  (rdd1, rdd2, (blocking: Boolean) => tempRDD.unpersist(blocking))
}
```

[image: idea debug]