# Debugger cannot see local variable in a Lambda

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I noticed that when I hover my mouse over a local variable when my debugger is stopped inside a lambda it will report `Cannot find local variable 'variable_name'` even if it's visible inside the lambda and it's used.

Example code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "hello_world";
        m1(a);
    }

    private static void m1(String a) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<String>) () -> {
            System.out.println("blala " + a);
            return "abc";
        });
    }
}
```

Try with a breakpoint in `System.out.println("blala " + a);` and after `return "abc"` and it always report the same error.

[image]

I used `AccessController.doPrivileged` because it's what I used in my original code and of course i'm using Java 8.

It says the same thing in `Watchers` and `Evaluate Expression`.

I tried using the "anonymous  class" version and the debugger sees the value of `a` correctly

[image]

```
private static void m1(String a) {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
        @Override
        public String run() {
            System.out.println("blala " + a);
            return "abc";
        }
    });
}
```

I'm missing something about lambda expressions or it's an IntellIJ IDEA 14 bug?

I don't want to report the bug right now because I already reported a bug that was caused by my code instead of IntellIJ IDEA, so I want to be sure before do something (and because I don't use Java 8 so often, so I could be wrong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a know issue. According to JetBrains the root causes of this behavior is with the JDK. For more info see: [IDEA-126257](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126257)

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm what is written in IDEA bug report linked by Mike Rylander: this is a JDK bug and **update to version 8u60_25 of the JDK solves it**.