# IntelliJ debugger can't find a variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I am inside a lambda with the debugger and intelliJ is not able to display some variables. In this example (the breakpoint is just below the code): 
[image]

[image]

IntelliJ is not able to find the "bidRequest" object. Any idea of what I am doing wrong? I am on intelliJ 15.

Comment: It could [possibly be a JDK issue?](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126257)

Comment: Maybe this thread would help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895708/debugger-cannot-see-local-variable-in-a-lambda
It looks very similar to your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're "stopped" at the correct location? Have a look in the stack frame to the left. Push "go to source" button if you need to - and verify you end up in the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated java from 1.8.0_25 to 1.8.0_102 and it works !